# nhibernate mapping, map value to key

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Lets say I have two tables:

```
Tasks
  -TaskName
  -CategoryID

Categories
  -ID
  -Name
```

Now, lets say that I have a class:

```
Task
  string Name
  string Category
```

How do I map this so that when I save a Task object, it will lookup the category id for the given category name and store it in the CategoryID field?

Is it possible to map with Fluent nHibernate?

Comment: What if the entered category name doesn't exist? This is doable (with `property-ref`) and I can help you with the code, but I don't think it's a good domain design.

Comment: If the category name doesn't exist, its an error. The reason for this design, is that on one side there is a public api exposing 'readable' values, on the other side there is a legacy database full of internal ids. I would love for you to show an example mapping, but I will definitely check out ´property-ref´.

Comment: You shouldn't expose your internal domain model as a public API, nor let NHibernate go all the way down and crash. Instead, create a domain model with a proper Category reference (mapped by id) and perform a query by name. If no results are returned, you can return an error.

Comment: Well, its part of what we are trying to to here - hiding the internals with as little effort as possible. The categories are well known categories - not part of our domain. I can see no reason for putting extra logic in our code for this if nHibernate can do it for us. 
So if I want nHibernate to do that query for me, and return an error if it fails - how would I map it?

Comment: Scratch what I said earlier. It's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, nor recommended to have a **domain** `Task` class designed like that (it **is** possible to reference the `Category` by name, but you'd have to store the name instead of the ID in the `Task` table)

Instead, you need to separate your public API from your internal domain model:

```
class Domain.Task
{
    //From your description, I'm assuming this is an assigned unique id, even though
    //that's not great either
    public virtual string TaskName { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

class Domain.Category
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

class API.Task
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

And the method that receives the task:

```
public void CreateTask(API.Task task)
{
    session.Save(new Domain.Task
                 {
                     TaskName = task.Name,
                     Category = session.Query<Category>()
                                       .Single(x => x.Name == task.Category)
                 });
}
```

The end result is exactly what you want: tasks receive the category by name, and an error is thrown if the category does not exist.

Comment: Yes, this is what we ended up with. When it comes to separating api vs domain, it's exactly what we are doing. We are designing the api the way the api should be, even though it does not fit our internal domain model. There will be some kind of mapping in between, an I was hoping nhibernate could do that mapping for us. I see no point in 'stuffing' more code in between the layers than necessary. As long as the API is settled, you can always make the parts in between more complicated later if necessary.